# Docker mount available in in-container shell, but not from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a strange situation where a shell launched from within the container is able to see a mounted volume, but any `CMD` cannot see that volume for some reason.

I have the following source tree:

```
[~/workspace/docker-test]$ tree
.
├── Dockerfile
└── source
    └── file.txt

1 directory, 2 files
```

where Dockerfile is

```
FROM ubuntu:jammy as prereqs
RUN ls /usr/source
```

When I build and run the dockerfile, somehow it can't find the mounted directory

```
[~/workspace/docker-test]$ docker build -t docker-test . && docker run -it -v $(pwd)/source:/usr/source docker-test
[+] Building 1.6s (5/5) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 36B                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:jammy                         1.1s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:jammy@sha256:27cb6e6ccef575a4698b66f5de  0.0s
 => ERROR [2/2] RUN ls /usr/source                                                      0.3s
------
 > [2/2] RUN ls /usr/source:
#5 0.318 ls: cannot access '/usr/source': No such file or directory
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ls /usr/source]: exit code: 2
```

and yet when I run a shell from within the docker container, I'm able to find it just fine. New Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:jammy as prereqs
# RUN ls /usr/source
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Launches shell from which the mounted volume is perfectly visible.

```
[~/workspace/docker-test]$ docker build -t docker-test . && docker run -it -v $(pwd)/source:/usr/source docker-test
[+] Building 0.6s (5/5) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 111B                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:jammy                         0.6s
 => CACHED [1/1] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:jammy@sha256:27cb6e6ccef575a4698b66f5de  0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                  0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                 0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:aa762c0645f70aea2a82508f0654abb2aadb27d2abf7e971b5eed85a7e  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/docker-test                                          0.0s

root@d8b3952e2e80:/# ls /usr/source/
file.txt
```

I don't understand why it's not visible in the Dockerfile but perfectly visible in the container shell!

Answer (score 2):

`RUN ls /usr/source` is running on `docker build`, but `CMD` is executed on `docker run`. Volume can't be mounted when image building, so you have to use `COPY` command inside dockerfile to be able access external resources inside image.

QA:

> If I were toRUN make after using COPY to make the source visible, those changes would only stay within the container. Any guidance on the right strategy here?

The proper way depends on your needs and environment. Here is two possible ways:

1. **If storing of built application locally is necessary**: a. Mount external volume and run container with building process, b. Run another container that will use built code. It will be look like:

   ```
   $ docker build -t builder-image ./builder && \
     docker run -it -v $(pwd)/source:/usr/source builder-image && \
     docker build -t docker-test ./runner && \
     docker run -it -v $(pwd)/source:/usr/source docker-test
   ```

   where `builder-image`'s `Dockerfile` will be look like:

   ```bash
   FROM ubuntu:jammy
   # install libraries or dependencies to be able build app
   RUN ...
   # run build (CMD will be applied on docker run command when volume is already mounted)
   CMD ["clang-tidy", "-fix-errors", "..."]
   ```
2. **If storing of built application locally is NOT necessary**: [Multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) is a most common practice in this way, but built application will be stored directly inside docker image in this case (Actually, what is correct behavior for most cases, especially in production). And `Dockerfile` will be like

   ```bash
   # create builder image
   FROM ubuntu:jammy as builder
   # copy source files
   COPY /usr/source .
   # install libraries or dependencies to be able build app
   RUN ...
   # run build inside image build process
   RUN clang-tidy -fix-errors ...

   # create application runner image
   FROM ubuntu:jammy as builder
   # copy built application to new image
   COPY --from=builder /dir/where/app/built ./
   # run built application on docker run
   CMD ["./built_app_exec_file"]
   ```

<sub>Also [here](https://vsupalov.com/cache-docker-build-dependencies-without-volume-mounting/) is a good article about docker builds that may be useful</sub>

Comment: Ah, interesting. In my actual application, I'm trying to run commands that affect external files (e.g. clang-tidy -fix-errors). If I were to`RUN make` after using COPY to make the source visible, those changes would only stay within the container. Any guidance on the right strategy here?

Comment: @cydonian added info to answer

Answer (score 1):

Volumes are only mounted at run-time. As you can see on your `build` and `run` commands, the volume specification is only on the `docker run` command.